# Work out a users Interested tags for them automatically

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I'm far too lazy to figure out what tags I should add to my Interested tags list in order to get the best viewing experience.

I propose that Stack Overflow should work out what questions I'm interested in based on my questions, answers, comments, favourites and maybe even a little bit based on my views (a bit like how Last.fm figures out what music I'm interested in)

- **Its less work for the user.**
- It will hopefully give a better chance of highlighting the questions that a user is likely to participate in (based on their past actions), rather that the questions that the user *thinks* they are likely to participate in.

If anyone is interested in a tag that they haven't previously participated in then it seems likely that they should be searching instead (although it seems like a good idea to weigh in favour of question types that the user has been participating in recently so that if they pick up a new technology suitable questions will be highlighted)

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/help-us-redesign-the-stack-overflow-homepage/69085#69085

Comment: @Robert - Yeah, I've seen that - related (possibly inspired by), but I'd like to see this on pages other than the homepage.