# How come a tag becomes listed in favorite tags

Tags: support, tag-watching

I just want to know how a tag gets listed in favorites even when I don't do anything to make a tag to be my favorite?

Comment: Do you mean it's actually shown in the favorites list, or just that it starts getting highlighted? It might be related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72587/145982)

Comment: Which site?  One of the Q&A sites, or Careers?

Comment: What tags on what site exactly? If you remove them, do they come back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't added any favorite tags, the system infers some implicit favorite tags for you based on your activity.

See these questions for some details:

- [Why is Stack Overflow suddenly orange (#FFEFC6)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange)
- [Why are "etymology" questions on german.sx highlighted for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96389/why-are-etymology-questions-on-german-sx-highlighted-for-me)
- [Please let users opt out of the "frequented tag" system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/please-let-users-opt-out-of-the-frequented-tag-system)

Comment: Yes, I saw this in webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Should [Work out a users Interested tags for them automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69108/work-out-a-users-interested-tags-for-them-automatically) be marked `status-completed`?

Comment: Most annoying feature ever, but true. As far as marking that request `[status-completed]`, as-implemented I'm not sure if it's *quite* the same thing, but it's probably close enough that it would normally have been marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

The tags that appear in your "Favorite Tags" list are added by you. It could be you added a tag in that list by mistake.

If you hover the mouse over a tag listed under a question, you will see a pop-up; if then you click on the star shown at the beginning, that tag is added to your favorite tags.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The last screenshot shows how I see the tags in the "Favorite Tags" list with Safari 5.1; the image has not been modified in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't added to your favourite list automatically, you have to put it manually.

If you have some favourite tags you did not add, it's probably bug.

Comment: I believe that I have not added anything upto my knowledge. That's why I got this doubt