# How many times do I have to answer a question with a tag before it is automatically marked as interesting?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

On webmasters.stackexchange.com I have set no favorite tags. Recently questions with the tag `seo` have started being highlighted as if it were one of my favorite tags (in a fetching light blue). Looking at my profile I've answered 69 seo questions, and it's my top tag. Is there a number of times I have to answer a question with a specific tag before it gets marked as interesting?

Or is there some other algorithm behind marking those seo questions as interesting?

Comment: The automatic highlighting is time dependent. Meaning that it depends on the number of view of questions of that tag divide by fixed time interval. Let me try to see if I can find the question where the algorithm is given.

Comment: Ah, found it: see this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100019/155238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual "inferred interesting tags" algorithm -- or at least what it was last December -- is [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593) (which is not the same as the one Willie linked).