# Why does the question filter always return 96 questions?

Tags: support, filtering, new-nav, newest-questions

After the [latest improvement to the new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration), I can now see question counts.  I noticed that my preferred settings (new questions, recommended tags, sort by active) returns a set of 96 questions.

What (if any) is the significance of 96 questions?

> [image: 96 question for settings]

Comment: Cross site dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299057/why-does-the-new-recommended-tab-give-always-96-questions

Comment: Wow. Usually I have the opposite problem where my MSO post is a MSE dup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the historical number of questions that we put on the homepage.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/help-us-redesign-the-stack-overflow-homepage).