# Can we make the recommended view in the question list contain 100 instead of 96 questions?

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, question-lists

Maybe my OCD is kicking in, but I do get a little frustrated with 96 questions on the recommended view in the new navigation. It seems to [always have been like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261337/why-does-the-question-filter-always-return-96-questions)...

[image: screen shot]

Can we please change it to be 100?

Comment: 96 is special! It was chosen because "Ninety-six is an octagonal number, a refactorable number and an untouchable number. Since it is a multiple of 6, it is a semiperfect number. The many divisors cause 96 to be an abundant number.

Ninety-six is the fourth Granville number and the second non-perfect Granville number...

The sum of Euler's totient function φ(x) over the first seventeen integers is 96... Every integer greater than 96 may be represented as a sum of distinct super-prime numbers..." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/96_%28number%29))

Comment: Okay, so we like 96. But I still have OCD...

Comment: The UI hints that maybe the four questions that didn't fit were the good ones... giving you hope... Otherwise, a client-side script `if (number is 96) {show 100 instead}` can help with the OCD part.

Comment: **O**xford **C**ontemporary **D**ictionary? **O**versimplified **C**rowded **D**ormitories? **O**lder **C**reepy **D**omains?