# Active vs. Interesting questions

Tags: discussion, questions, interesting-page

Why did you name the main question feed differently across the platform?

- On [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (and other randomly checked sites) the list of question is named **active**
- On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) the list is named **interesting**

Hope I'm not too pedantic with this question.

Comment: [How it all started](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/help-us-redesign-the-stack-overflow-homepage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different things.

Active - means sorted by activity date (asked, edited, answered mostly).

Interesting - a more complex sorting algorithm, takes all sorts of bits of information into account (at different weights). Mostly black art - we found *something* that seems to work well.

Stack Overflow gets a different sorting because - at the rate questions come in and are updated, things change incredibly quickly. Active just isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Great! Your last edit answered my question completely (I'll accept in a few minutes). Thanks

Comment: The difference is not related to the [new-nav](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration), right?

Comment: @rene - I don't think new-nav has an "interesting" sort. That sort predates it.

Comment: Oh, but just to know better, will this link will sort the questions on stackexchange with the algorithem of SO? http://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=interesting (Because I do see different list)

Comment: @AlonEitan - not sure. Would have to look at the code for that.

Comment: "things change incredibly quickly" - while true of course, I think the goal of the "interesting" algorithm is to help you sift through the huge amount of questions, and find those you will find, well, interesting. :)